# Visual Studio Test task fails randomly without error message, Exit code 1 returned from process: node.exe

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have this issue that has been plaguing our engineering group for over a year and we cannot make any progress on the resolution. This [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831343/vsts-task-fails-intermittently-with-exit-code-1-returned-from-node-exe) is eerily similar to what we experience.

We have several pipelines that use the "Visual Studio Test" task to run a set of NUnit tests from a single assembly. There are 1400-1500 unit tests in the project and it takes The NUnit Test Adapter is deployed via the NuGet task (install NUnit3TestAdapter). This test assembly is built with the following settings:

- MSBuild Architecture=x86
- Platform=AnyCPU
- Configuration=Release
- Strong Name Signed

Across multiple pipelines, this step randomly yet consistently ends early with zero error message or trace of why the process ended. Running a subsequent build of the pull request will often result in a success but occasionally another failure. In this case we have coined this a "flaky build" where given the same exact code inputs, the build can fail and then subsequently pass.

This is the only error message we received from the pipeline:

> ##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'REDACTED\externals\node\bin\node.exe', arguments '"REDACTED_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\runvstest.js"'.
> Finishing: Integration Tests

These tests are our "integration tests" that perform many setup steps to create a functional version of our system including creating a web server via Kestrel to host our API, connect to (localdb) running on the build server to restore a database .bak file and apply a database project (dacpac) as well as connect to Redis (also installed locally on the build server).

We are struggling to determine next steps so I am reaching out to the community to see if anyone else has suffered through this issue, has ideas for how to debug the issue or perhaps even a solution!

edit on 2020-11-10

Yesterday I set the pipeline variable `system.debug` to true and this is the output it captured during one of our flaky builds.

```
##[error\]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'E:\\servername\\externals\\node\\bin\\node.exe', arguments '"E:\\servername\\\_work\\\_tasks\\VSTest\_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\\2.170.1\\runvstest.js"'.

##[debug\]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException: Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'E:\\servername\\externals\\node\\bin\\node.exe', arguments '"E:\\servername\\\_work\\\_tasks\\VSTest\_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\\2.170.1\\runvstest.js"'.

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary\`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue\`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary\`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue\`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary\`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync()

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()

  at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
```

Comment: From the error message, it is still difficult to find the specific cause of this issue. The error message shows that the vstest task has some issues.  It seems that you are using self-hosted agent, right?  You could try to remove the folder `VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9` and check if it could make some changes

Comment: On the other hand, you can try to set variable `system.debug = true` to get the debug log, so you can check if there are more error messages. Please share the vstest task definition too.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT please see my edit. I added extra message info from `system.debug`.

Comment: In the last few days, I have tested the vstest task many times, but I still can’t reproduce the problem. Although it is a debug log, it still does not contain more error information.  Could you please check the node version on your agnet? My node version is 10.16. You could try to update the node version and check if it could make changes.

Comment: Agent itself had node 12 something installed. The task was bundled with a node.exe of version 6 something. As of today we abandoned the VS Test task in favor a direct call to powershell.exe and nunit3-console.exe.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You may share the workaround in the answer and accept it. It could be helpful.